# How to correctly configure Alerting yaml rules for Prometheus / Alertmanager

Tags: yaml, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

since i'm having a horrid time configuring the Alerting rules for the Prometheus Alertmanager, maybe someone can give me an hint in the right direction.

Here are the rules i'm currently trying to implement (taken straight from:
https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/alerting_rules/)

rules.yml:

```
groups:
- name: example
  rules:

  # Alert for any instance that is unreachable for >5 minutes.
  - alert: InstanceDown
    expr: up == 0
    for: 5m
    labels:
      severity: page
    annotations:
      summary: "Instance {{ $labels.instance }} down"
      description: "{{ $labels.instance }} of job {{ $labels.job }} has been down for more than 5 minutes."

  # Alert for any instance that has a median request latency >1s.
  - alert: APIHighRequestLatency
    expr: api_http_request_latencies_second{quantile="0.5"} > 1
    for: 10m
    annotations:
      summary: "High request latency on {{ $labels.instance }}"
      description: "{{ $labels.instance }} has a median request latency above 1s (current value: {{ $value }}s)"
```

with the amtool and promtool config check i'm getting the following error:

```
Checking '/etc/prometheus/rules.yml'  FAILED: yaml: unmarshal errors:
  line 1: field groups not found in type config.plain

amtool: error: failed to validate 1 file(s)
```

My first guess would be a wrong indentation or some other kind of yaml-syntax error.
However i've tried with multiple Alerting rules and also with different files as well as editors (currently i'm using nano).The yaml has also been checked with multiple yaml Linters.
But for the time being i've always had errors in the line of the one shown.

Any help or suggestion would greatly be appreciated!

```
prometheus, version 2.22.2 (branch: HEAD, revision: de1c1243f4dd66fbac3e8213e9a7bd8dbc9f38b2)
  go version:       go1.15.5
  platform:         linux/amd64
```

```
alertmanager, version 0.21.0 (branch: HEAD, revision: 4c6c03ebfe21009c546e4d1e9b92c371d67c021d)
  go version:       go1.14.4
```

yaml linters:

https://codebeautify.org/yaml-validator

https://onlineyamltools.com/validate-yaml

tested alerting rules:

https://onlineyamltools.com/validate-yaml

https://grafana.com/blog/2020/02/25/step-by-step-guide-to-setting-up-prometheus-alertmanager-with-slack-pagerduty-and-gmail/

https://rakeshjain-devops.medium.com/prometheus-alerting-most-common-alert-rules-e9e219d4e949

https://github.com/vegasbrianc/prometheus/blob/master/prometheus/alert.rules

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The unmarshal of `groups` fails because it is supposed to be a list:

```
groups:
- name: GroupName
  rules:
  - alert: ...
```

See the [documentation about recording rules](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/recording_rules/#recording-rules) which is the same as the alerting rules.

---

UPDATE after post was corrected

Your file seems to be correct. The command line is:

```
promtool check rules /etc/prometheus/rules.yml
```

I expect you used the command to check the `config` and not the `rules`.

Please note that `amtool` validates AlertManager's config, not Prometheus'.

Comment: thanks for the comment, it seems i've posted the wrong rule.yml (tried multiple). The post is now edited and contains the rule.yml i'm currently checking. It's just copy&paste from the alerting rules docu, but i'm still getting the same error :/

Comment: Thank you so much, you made my day! The error was indeed the check rules! What still boggles me a bit is, i tried to load the given rules.yml without checking it first with the promtool (but still exactly the same file)  and the Prometheus Service was not able to correctly load the File?

Comment: Without the exact error, I cannot tell. The `rules.yml` file is included by the `prometheus.yml` file sot the error was matbe not in this file.